# How facebook knows all user connections so fast?

Tags: facebook, http, cookies, architecture, social-networking

I'm developing a service, that uses social graph.

There is a separate module, that manages user connections, that is basically responsible for all related operations. In some services, you need to know all user connections, to provide correct responses.

The way I see it there are 4 possible options to implement this:

1. Server based connection support.

   1.1. Each time social graph data requested ask for friend list from the module, and process corresponding response.

   1.2. Have internal cache with Key - playerID, Value - all player connections, add responsibility to update this cache to connection module, and use it instead of referring to this module.
2. Client based connection support.

   2.1. Add a special Cookie with the list of all friends, so that server could just read that Cookie and provide needed information, without talking to the external module. (This can be secured, by for example providing some signature for the Cookie, and optimised by adding some path, for all the connections related data)

   2.2. Add a connection management layer in Client, so it would explicitly request all needed information, by providing a list of connections on each request.

As I look at facebook Cookies, there is a fr cookie, which I can speculate used for this kind of functionality.

How facebook solves this?

Comment: Why don't you ask facebook?

Comment: 10k+ link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891873/how-does-facebook-achieve-good-performance i dont have installed any screen shot tools may be other 10k+ help

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to maintain a list of friends for each user you don't need a full social graph. A simple list of friends stored in your database would work fine.

Client-side storage is typically only for caching or session data, you don't want your users losing their friend list because they re-installed their browser or switched computers.

If you do want to implement a full social graph have a look for a graph DB. [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/developer/get-started/) is one I've used and is fairly easy to get started on.